Battery charging slow
I have 2 batteries connected in  series (each battery rating - 3.3V and 5Ah). So the combine effect after connecting in series is 7.3V 5Ah (practically getting 7.56V in the battery)[the battery has max voltage aka full charging voltage of 8.4V] so i want to charge the battery upto 8.4V and i calculated the charging current of the battery (5Ah × 10% = 0.5A so practically i have to supply it till 0.8A current). Now whats happening is i am using a module for Ac to dc which can give 12V 6-8A as output. Now i tried using voltage divider as well as buck converter circuits (used individually one at time not together!) to scale down the voltage to around 8.4V to supply it to battery. The main problem i am facing is its charging current. When i used a voltage divider circuit the charging current was 0.014A which is very low compared to what it needs to be theoretical. After using buck converter the battery is pulling 0.2A of current. Now the thing i am not understanding is even though i am giving it enough current to pull its not pulling the current it is expected to pull (0.8-0.5) and if i keep it to charge as it is 0.2A it will take a heck lot of time for the battery to charge. What can do so that the battery pulls the current as expected by it and charge faster. I known there is a concept of regulators but cant this work get done without regualators ?

Do NOT use random power sources to charge your battery. Do NOT even think about applying the output across the battery directly. Battery charging is a complex process i.e. the voltage, the current, and even the temperature should be constantly monitored for safety and preserved life. Use a proper battery charger for your battery (voltage/current/capacity and chemistry).

I am using 2S 3A 18650 module i am not charging the batteries directly i am aware of that. The module is between the batteries and charging circuit for safety.

Pictures + Schematic = Answer

@LLawlit You have no charging circuit in the photo. The photo shows a very dangerous setup without a charging circuit.

Please disconnect that battery right now and stop abusing it without a charger.
Mishandled batteries degrade and damage and damaged batteries may explode or burst into flames starting a fire.
You cannot connect batteries to a constant voltage output of a buck converter.
Buck converters are not lithium chargers and cannot be used to charge lithium batteries.
Whatever voltage you set the buck converter output to, the battery will clamp the output voltage to it's value and the buck converter will try to get back up to the set value but it can never push enough current to raise the voltage to setpoint so no amount of current it outputs raises the voltage to setpoint and the buck converter simply shuts off due to overcurrent protection.
What you need is not a buck converter, but a lithium charger.
A BMS is also not a charger either.
Only a charger is a charger.

Thank you, just the explanation i needed, i wanted to make my own charging circuit but it seems its a very dangerous setup will take that into consideration and buy tp5100 (module for this rating)
